# Prevent jQuery mobile button default behaviour

Tags: jquery, cordova

EDIT: To clarify I do want the #capture-photo button to get active, but I want to reset it when I navigate to another page programmatically.

I'm currently building a Phonegap/Cordova app using jQuery as framework. Most is well - except one scenario.

I have a fixed footer (works great) with navbar and three buttons.

Two buttons go to regular pages no ajax and they work great.

One buttons hooks to the Camera interface and triggers the camera on the (i.e.) iPhone. If I cancel i get back to the screen but the button for the camera now has active state and styling.

I am triggering a changePage on failure and the page get's activate but it does not change the button state!? I've tried to manually remove the classes without success!? Something seems to delay the adding of classes for active state until or something.

Am I doing it wrong? Shouldn't the changePage() find and trigger it's anchor?

In the album page the footer looks like this:

```
  <div class="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer-tab">
    <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish">
     <ul>
        <li><a id="welcome" href="#welcome"></a></li>
        <li><a id="capture-photo"></a></li>
        <li><a id="show-album" href="#album" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So again - the #capture-photo button does NOT have a corresponding page, but when I click it gets activated, if I cancel the camera - jqm catchers a changePage and goes to the #show-album, but the #capture-photo button is still marked as active.

P.S I do have an identical footer (data-role='footer') on both pages except their respective anchor has the ui-btn-active and ui-state-persist set. I feel a bit uncomfortable with this duplicate code but it seems the only way to solve the persisted headers/footers?

Comment: You mean like doing e.preventDefault(); on click?

Comment: Not really :( I clarified it a bit in the edit.

Comment: Now I tried manually triggering it like so: `$('#album #show-album').trigger('vclick')` after running `$.mobile.changePage('#album')` and it actually works BUT when I navigate to the #welcome page then it gets activated again(!?!?) - so now both the #welcome-page AND the #capture-photo are active(!?!?).

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved it in a bit of an ugly way unfortunately. Before running $.mobile.changePage('#album') i manually trigger the 'vclick' event on all the fixed footer navbars. Ugly, but for now it works… :o

```
// HATE DOING THIS! BUT JQM IS NOT WORKING WITH ME ON THIS.
  $('#welcome #show-album').trigger('vclick')
  $('#album #show-album').trigger('vclick')
```